# Guacamole SSH disconnecting, no keyboard

Tags: guacamole

I'm using Guacamole `0.9.12-incubating` - on server-side extending `GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet`, on client using official JavaScript code. Guacamole server is compiled from source and is running on Ubuntu 17.04.

SSH connection is successfully **established, but disconnects after 15 seconds**. No keyboard strokes nor mouse are working.

```
May  7 17:14:09 dev guacd[4071]: Creating new client for protocol "ssh"
May  7 17:14:09 dev guacd[4071]: Connection ID is "$30e2e833-5640-4bc9-92c3-929ced3d6e0e"
May  7 17:14:09 dev guacd[4382]: User "@4209df46-e26a-4ced-93c4-c264578f85a5" joined connection "$30e2e833-5640-4bc9-92c3-929ced3d6e0e" (1 users now present)
May  7 17:14:10 dev guacd[4382]: SSH connection successful.
May  7 17:14:24 dev guacd[4382]: User is not responding.
May  7 17:14:24 dev guacd[4382]: User "@4209df46-e26a-4ced-93c4-c264578f85a5" disconnected (0 users remain)
May  7 17:14:24 dev guacd[4382]: Last user of connection "$30e2e833-5640-4bc9-92c3-929ced3d6e0e" disconnected
May  7 17:14:25 dev guacd[4382]: SSH connection ended.
May  7 17:14:25 dev guacd[4071]: Connection "$30e2e833-5640-4bc9-92c3-929ced3d6e0e" removed.
```

Client JavaScript is the same as in documentation - https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html .

When I `Override` methods in servlet, they show me that key strokes go to it. So problem is probably somewhere between servlet and guacd?

```
@Override
protected void doWrite(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String tunnelUUID) throws GuacamoleException {
        LOGGER.debug("Do WRITE to session " + tunnelUUID);
        super.doWrite(request, response, tunnelUUID);
    }

@Override
protected void doRead(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String tunnelUUID) throws GuacamoleException {
        LOGGER.debug("Do read to session " + tunnelUUID);
        super.doRead(request, response, tunnelUUID);
    }
```

Connection is established, but no key strokes are working:
[image: SSH connection established (in browser)]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Spring Boot, as discussed there - https://glyptodon.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/GUAC-1252/GUAC-1252.html .

Solution is to create own implementation of `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`:

```
@Configuration
public class GuacamoleServletConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GuacamoleServlet guacamoleTunnelServlet() {
        return new GuacamoleServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(guacamoleTunnelServlet(), "/remote/tunnel");
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/remote/tunnel")) {
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```